# CSS Animation back to default

Tags: css, css-animations

If I have an element with default `opacity: 0.8` for example, and I have a general basic fade-in animation `0% = opacity: 0, 100% = opacity: 1`, can I set the value of `opacity: 1` to default?
So in this case 100% would be `opacity: 0.8`, and if I use the same animation on a different element with default `opacity: 0.5`, the 100% would be 0.5 automatically.

Is it possible?

Comment: You may use CSS var() from elements themselves (inside the CSS selector) to set the opacity value. Would have an example to share, so you could try and then show you how if you have issues?

Comment: Vars doesn't help me, because it will still just set one value to the animation. I want a flexible value so that I'm able to use one animation for any element no matter what default opacity it has, this way I don't have to create a new animation for every single element that has a unique default opacity.

Comment: You probably misunderstand the use of var() in my comment. 1 keyframe with a var() for opacity. and a different var() value for each elements. Set an example of your HTML also, to demonstrate your issue. It can be used to demonstrate the power of var() css then. My last call trying to help you ;) Basicly, yes it is possible.

Comment: Interesting, can you give an example of what that would look like? What determines which var is being used in each individual case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the animation with only `opacity:0`

```css
.box {
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
  width:150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation:fade-in 2s 1s backwards;
}


@keyframes fade-in {
  from {opacity:0}
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="opacity:0.8"></div>
<div class="box" style="opacity:0.5"></div>
```